# Want to use JQUERY to cause post of a single selected form value

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post, submit

I'm generating an array of key/values and scrolling through it to produce a set of 'a' tags within a form.
I want JQuery to detect which one of the 'a' tags has been clicked, and submit the form, so that the KEY is posted, not the value.
The JQuery function does not seem to be working in the test.php file I built.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    echo '<h2>URL parameter passed by $_GET</h2>' ;
    echo '<pre>' ;
        echo print_r($_GET) ;
    echo '</pre>' ; 
} elseif(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    echo '<h2>URL parameter passed by $_POST</h2>' ;
    echo '<pre>' ;
        echo print_r($_POST) ;
    echo '</pre>' ; 
}

?>
<style>
    table {
        width:50%;
    }
    td {
        width:25%;
        border:1pt solid black;
        margin:0px;
    }
</style>
<?php 
    // Build Indexed Array
    $fruit[0] = 'Orange' ;
    $fruit[1] = 'Apple' ;
    $fruit[2] = 'Banana' ;

    echo '<pre>' ;
        echo print_r($fruit) ;
    echo '</pre>' ; 

    // Form definition
    echo '<form name="groupform" id="groupform" action="test.php" method="post">' ;
    echo '<table>' ;
    echo '<tr><td>Array values</td><td>Simple A tag</td><td>Regular submit button</td><td>A tag with class submit</td></tr>' ;
    for($key = 0; $key < count($fruit); $key++) {
      echo '<tr>' ;
      // Array Values
      echo '<td>Index is ' . $key . ', value is ' . $fruit[$key] . '</td>' ;
      // Simple A tag
      echo '<td><a href="?id=' . $key . '">' . $fruit[$key] . '</a></td>' ;
      // Regular submit button
      echo '<td><input type="submit" name="id" id="id" value="' . $fruit[$key] . '"></td>' ;
      // A tag with class submit
      echo '<td><a href="" class="submit" name="id" id="id" value="' . $key . '">' . $fruit[$key] . '</a></td>' ;
      echo '</tr>' ;
    }
    echo '<tr><td></td><td>Functions correctly, but don&apos;t want to use a URL parameter to send the key</td><td>Can&apos;t get this to post the key instead of the value</td><td>Ideally want to style it as an a tag, but post the key</td></tr>' ;
    echo '</table>' ;
    echo '</form>' ;
 ?>
<script src="/scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
    // when clicking the submit button
    $('.submit').click(function(){
        // Get the value of the clicked a tag
        var usethisID = $(this).val();
        alert(usethisID);
        // submit the form
        // BUT POST the value of usethisID as id
        $('#groupform').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You haven't included the jQuery library in this snippet, and `$` won't be recognised as a reference to jQuery until you explicitly set it.

Comment: Thanks Dan, noob error! I've added it just before the JQuery function, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.
I think the problem lies in the function itself - surely this is saying "if the user clicks on an element with class submit, then submit the form. But it does not 'read' the value for the a tag that was actually clicked and make it the one that the form submits. Am I hunting in the right area?

Comment: Sorry, it IS now reading a value into usethisID but it looks to be empty and I still haven't instructed JQuery to send this value as part of the post.

Answer (score 0):

var usethisID = $(this).attr("value");

Be carreful, in the DOM, you can not have tags with the same 'id' !!!
Each id='' must have an UNIQUE value !
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id

So I propose to construct each 'id' with the $key inside : id_XXXX

```
echo '<td><a href="" class="submit" name="id" id="id_'.$key.'" value="' . $key . '">' . $fruit[$key] . '</a></td>' ;
```

In jQuery, you extract the $key from the id :

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    // when clicking the submit button
    $('.submit').click(function(){
        // Get the value of the clicked a tag
        var index = $(this).attr("id");
        var usethisID = index.substring(index.indexOf("_")+1 );

        alert(usethisID);

        // submit the form
        // BUT POST the value of usethisID as id
        $('#groupform').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Good continuation.

*_Teddy_*

Comment: Thanks Teddy. That worked well, useThisID is definitely being set correctly now. My function's still not posting the value properly, but I will work through that....